# Require error in app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I recently started working on a new game written in nodejs and for some reason its not letting me use require in the app.js which I know for a fact its possible because I made other games like this

This is the error I am recieving in my console on the website
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at app.js:2`

And this is the code its reffering too

```html
var socket;
var pg = require('pg');

var config = require('../../config.json');

var conString = config.database.uri;

var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();
```

This error is hendering the rest of my code from running and im almost certain that this line

`var config = require('../../config.json');`

Will produce an error as well after i fix the first

According to webpack npm and all my other projects doing putting `"build": "webpack"` is supposed to allow require in app.js but its not working

Here is my package.json

```html
{
  "name": "CodingIdleMasters",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Placeholder",
  "main": "server/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "node server/server.js"
  },
  "author": "FlamingGenius",
  "contributors": [
    "Joseph Williamson <deathcrow4561@gmail.com> (https://github.com/FlamingGenius)"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "socket.io": "^1.4.6",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.4.6",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-stream": "^3.2.0",
    "pg": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Here is a link to the project on github in case you need to see more code
[Github Project](https://github.com/flaminggenius/CodingIdleMasters)

In case that it helps heres my current hierarchy

```html
-client
 -css
  -main.css
 -js
  -app.js
  -game.js
  -menu.js
 -index.html
-server
 -server.js
-config.json
-package.json
```

EDIT:

Its seems i need the webpack config but the docs arnt really helpful in explaining how to set this up if anyone could possibly provide an answer explaining how to set it up and possible provide some code it would be very helpful

Comment: require is allowed but you don't have node_modules with pg library

Comment: this is my first time working with pg so how do i use it? cause thats what it says on the docs

Comment: use your nodejs command prompt and cd to you project path then type npm install pg, This should generate node_modules folder as it is not found in your project then add the pg library

Comment: this isnt really to do with pg itself i cant use require at all in my app.js file thats what i need to fix

Comment: @FlamingGenius Do you have a webpack.config.js file in your project.  If so, can you update your answer with the contents of that file?  That will tell us what webpack is (or is not) doing.

Comment: Ive never used one 0.o? I thought the build: webpack creates one automatically??

Comment: how u run your app.js ?

Comment: The full source code is on gothub in the link if you need to see the coding if your wondering what platforn i am using evennode on thier $6 plan

Comment: please add a simple layout of your file directory, so others can see what your missing.

Comment: I added a layout of my heiarchy

Comment: looks like your missing a webpack.config.js file, this piece of the [documentation](http://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/) should get you started.

Comment: using the same config from the other game wont work and i stopped working on that game specifically because the code became unorganized and unmanageable @alphapilgrim The docs are really confusing i tried the docs for node but they just crashed my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` is for use in NodeJS and not on the browser.

However, there are ways to get module imports to work properly in the browser. As mentioned before, WebPack is one way to do so. Setting up WebPack requires more than just adding the line to your package.json and installing the file - you will need a configuration file and proper building: https://webpack.js.org/guides/

First, make sure that your package.json has the correct dependencies (in this case `pg`) and that it is installed (check node_modules directory).

Assuming that all you want for now is JavaScript module loading you can use the following configuration file located at the root of your project (webpack.config.js):

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './client/app.js',
        game: './client/game.js',
        menu: './client/menu.js',
    },
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, '.'),
    devtool: 'source-map',
    target: 'web',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js'],
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'client'), 'node_modules']
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        modules: ['node_modules']
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'dist') // output into /client/dist
    }
};
```

This will take each of your files and bundle the scripts and its dependencies so that it'll work properly. Run it with `webpack --config webpack.config.js`. I've given you a very simplistic config - in a real use case one would probably pack all the main files into one bundle, instead of having one bundle for each script file. WebPack is a very powerful tool and you can potentially expand your usage but I will leave that up to you as I don't know the exact setup you have (the WebPack guides have tons of information).

That being said, connecting to the database from a client might be possible but it's certainly not recommended. First, the `pg` package is designed for usage on NodeJS. Second, database connections should always be handled by your server and the client should only ever interact with the server. Taking a look at your server, you're just serving the content currently without doing anything - all the things you're trying to do on the client with the database should be offloaded to the server.